# Does size matter?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, yoda

In The Empire Strikes Back Yoda tells Luke that:

> Size matters not, judge me by my size do you?

This always led me to believe that as The Force did the actual lifting it was only the belief of the force user in question that limited their force telekinesis.

However, in the prequels a lot is made of how powerful Anakin is (which presumably means he could perform force feats which others could not). I believe there are a few instances (perhaps in older canons) where he prevented AT-ATs from stepping on him and lifted two AT-DP walkers at the same time. I think it's safe to say the "average" jedi couldn't do this!

Was Yoda being truthful when he told Luke that "size matters not" or was it more of a pep talk to convince Luke that he could lift the X-wing?

Comment: Size matters not, density does!

Comment: It's all about how you use it.

Comment: I've actually voted to close my own question because one of the related questions looks too similar... happy to go with the consensus

Comment: @SteveHarrington I've removed `ESB` because the question is not limited to the film and therefore not about the film. Liath, I've removed the character tags since the question is not necessarily about those characters but is more of a question about the force. During my writing of this comment I've decided to add `yoda` back in as the question is clearly about that character, but merely references the other two. I however stand by the opinion that the question is **primarily** about `the-force`.

Comment: Gee, I wonder why Yoda likes to say size doesn't matter.